# Meaning of the word 'Vyasa'

Tags: dharma, sanskrit, vyasa, dharma-shastras

Ved Vyasa is a title which is given to new Vyasa in every Chaturyuga, in this Chaturyuga it is Given to the great Krishna Dwaipayana son of Bramharishi Parashara.

The word Vyasa is a related to Geometry, Vyasa is also a Sanskrit word for Diameter of a Circle.

What is the meaning of Vyasa when used as 'Veda Vyasa', is it Geometrical or something else?

---

**My Interpretation with the Meaning 'Diameter of Circle':**

If we compare the analogy we get the literal meaning as follows

> vedavyasa = Veda + Vyasa
>   Veda has two meanings Knowledge/ The 4 Vedas
>   Vyasa is Diameter

If we consider circle to be Veda (Circle of Knowledge or Vedas) then according to the definition of Diameter

> A line segment connecting two extreme points of the Circle(Knowledge) is known as Diameter of circle.

So if we compare the analogy we can derive following meaning

> Veda Vyasa means the entitled person for a Chaturyuga who has All the knowledge(of the vedas) from its two Extremes

Note: The possible reason for Analogy of circle to the Vedas/Knowledge is because Circle is a complete figure and Vedas are complete set knowledge.

Vedas don't have a starting point(apaurusheya)from this we can conclude that they don't have ending, similarly circle has no starting point which means no end point.

Comment: What is it with the cosmetics with the question?

Comment: I remember reading in Puranas that Veda vyasa is named such because of  "expansion of Vedas" as he wrote Puranas which are expansions of Vedas.

Comment: @TheDestroyer are you talking about meaning. no 4?

Comment: @SreeCharan Where is cosmetic in this question?

Comment: You added [tag:cosmetics] mistakenly. The Destroyer removed while editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Geometrical Meaning of the word Vyasa is misfit.

The meaning of Veda Vyasa is **'The Compiler of Vedas'** here, but in my opinion geometrical meaning can be applied here if properly interpreted.

> There are 9 Meanings of the word Vyasa
>
> 1. Distribution, separation into parts.
> 2. Dissolution or analysis of a compound.
> 3. Severalty, distinction.
> 4. Diffusion, extension; तस्यैव व्यासमिच्छामि ज्ञातुं ते भगवन् यथा Bhāg.6.4.2.
> 5. Width, breadth.
> 6. The diameter of a circle.
> 7. A fault in pronunciation.
> 8. Arrangement, compliation.
> 9. An Arranger, a compiler.

[Sanskrit Dictonary](http://sanskritdictionary.com/?q=%E0%A4%B5%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%B8&lang=sans&iencoding=iast&action=Search#a3)(refer to V.S. Apte)

**Most Relevant Meaning 'Compiler, Arranger'**

Krishna Dwaipayana Veda Vyasa compiled the Vedas in order to simplify their study, this is the best fit, and the meaning of the word Vyasa here is Arranger or compiler.
So Veda Vyasa Translates to 'The Compiler of Vedas' .

**Meaning No. 1 "Distinguisher"**

The one who distinguished the Vedas into three parts.

**Meaning No. 3 Distinction**

Veda Vyasa who makes Distinctions in Vedas based on the purpose of Knowledge he divided Vedas into three parts and further made Distinction of each part into Samhita, Bramhana, Aranyaka, and Upanishad.

Veda Vyasa translates to 'The one who Distinguised Vedas(Vast Knowledge)'.